# How is your pay decided?

Tags: splatoon-2

In Salmon Run, How is it decided how much P you get (to get the bonuses)?

We see the operation at the end that it's a P x Paygrade = Bonus Progression. But how is that P decided?

I think it's golden eggs combined with eggs, but if it is, what are the ratios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula (derived from [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbpI5.jpg) of the official strategy guide) is:

```
Points = Pay Grade * (Golden Eggs + (Power Eggs / 200))
```

So every 200 power eggs you get is equivalent to a golden egg, then that score is multiplied by your pay grade.